# Lua pattern match for dyanmic url path

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I have a requirement where I have to change and store the dynamic url path of the incoming request and store in our backend

Below is the sample url

```
GET /v1/merchants
```

With my Lua code I change that to

```
GET_/v1/merchants
```

Everything is good and exactly what I need. But the problem arises when I try it with dynamic path in url

For eg: `GET /v1/content/merchants/{string}`

The url could be `GET /v1/content/merchants/foo` or `GET /v1/content/merchants/bar`

I want to store the above format in backend  like `GET /v1/content/merchants/string` because I cannot store in backend `GET_/v1/content/merchants/foo` or `GET_/v1/content/merchants/bar` for every incoming request

Below is the code

```
local function get_method(request)
  local method, path, query_fragment = request:match("^(.+) ([^%?]+)(%??.*) .+$")
  if method and path then
    return method .. "_" .. path
  else
    return nil
  end
end

local function extract_usage(request)
  local usage_t =  {}
  local ts_method = get_method(request)
  if ts_method then
    usage_t[ts_method] = set_or_inc(usage_t, ts_method, 1)
    return build_querystring(usage_t)
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `{id}`? Any character but `/` at the end of the string or digits only?

Comment: {id} is dataType = string. It could be /v1/content/merchants/foo or /v1/content/merchants/bar. I understand your confusion and will edit the post.

Comment: I still do not understand where the trouble is. `GET /v1/merchants` does not match the `^(.+) ([^%?]+)(%??.*) .+$` pattern. Please post reproducible piece of code and expected output.

Comment: Please check **[this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sxGNrC)**. If I got you right, `get_method_updated` will make sure you do not get the underscored request parts as the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
local function get_method_updated(request)
  local method, path, query_fragment = request:match("^(.+) ([^%?]+)(%??.*) .+$")
  if method and path then
    if path:match('^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[%w_]+') ~= nil then
        return method .. " " .. path
    else
        return method .. "_" .. path
    end 
  else
    return nil
  end
end

print(get_method_updated("GET /v1/merchants something"))
print(get_method_updated("GET /v1/content/merchants/foo or"))
print(get_method_updated("GET /v1/content/merchants/bar some"))
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/sxGNrC).

Output:

```
GET_/v1/merchants
GET /v1/content/merchants/foo
GET /v1/content/merchants/bar
```

The `get_method_updated` will make sure you do not get the underscored request parts as the return value.